# Whitespace in a database field is not removed by trim()

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, whitespace, trim

I have some whitespace at the begining of a paragraph in a text field in MySQL.

Using `trim($var_text_field)` in PHP or `TRIM(text_field)` in MySQL statements does absolutely nothing. What could this whitespace be and how do I remove it by code?

If I go into the database and backspace it out, it saves properly. It's just not being removed via the trim() functions.

Comment: what datatype is the columns, `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`?

Comment: some code would really help in answering.

Comment: Is this plain text or are you using different encoding?

Comment: @krok: the field is `text` 
@JohnP: it's being stored as UTF8_general

Comment: it's non-breaking space character. see updated answer

Answer (score 13):

```
function UberTrim($s) {
    $s = preg_replace('/\xA0/u', ' ', $s);  // strips UTF-8 NBSP: "\xC2\xA0"
    $s = trim($s);
    return $s;
}
```

The UTF-8 character encoding for a no-break space, Unicode (U+00A0), is the [2-byte sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings) `C2` `A0`.  I tried to make use of the [second parameter to `trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) but that didn't do the trick.  Example use:

```
assert("abc" === UberTrim("  \r\n  \xc2\xa0  abc  \t \xc2\xa0   "));
```

---

A MySQL replacement for `TRIM(text_field)` that also removes UTF no-break spaces, thanks to @RudolfRein's comment:

```
TRIM(REPLACE(text_field, '\xc2\xa0', ' '))
```

---

## UTF-8 checklist:

(more checks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/766809/673991))

1. Make sure your **PHP** source code editor is in [image: Encode in UTF-8 without BOM (Notepad++)] [UTF-8 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1388624/673991) **[without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2558172/673991)**.  Or set in the [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11517786/673991).
2. Make sure your **MySQL** client is set for UTF-8 character encoding (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/673991) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1317239/673991)), e.g.

   `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=...;dbname=...;charset=utf8',$userid,$password);`
   `$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");`
3. Make sure your **HTTP** server is set for UTF-8, e.g. for [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/913885/673991):

   `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`
4. Make sure the **browser** expects UTF-8.

   `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

   or

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Thanks to @tchrist suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262978/673991) about the 'u' flag in preg_replace().

Comment: YESS thank you !!! my sql data has stange spaces in it... I solved thanks to your \xc2\xa0 like this:

    WHERE REPLACE(rowname, '\xc2\xa0', ' ') LIKE '$searchstring%'

Answer (score 7):

If the problem is with UTF-8 NBSP, another simple option is:

```
REPLACE(the_field, UNHEX('C2A0'), ' ')
```

Comment: oh! simple and perfect

Comment: Just as a reference for beginners, the full query is; UPDATE `table_name` SET `the_field` = REPLACE(`the_field`, UNHEX('C2A0'), ' ')

Comment: what a great trick! I started to have an headache here. TY!

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is a combination of a few things mentioned to you already.

First run ORD() on the string in question. In my case I had to run a reverse first because my problem character was at the end of the string.

```
ORD(REVERSE([col name]))
```

Once you discover the problematic char, run a

```
REPLACE([col_name], char([char_value_returned]), char(32))
```

Finally, call a proper

```
TRIM([col_name])
```

This will completely eradicate the problem character from all aspects of the string, and trim off the leading (in my case trailing) character.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the MySQL `ORD()` function on the `text_field` to check the character code of the left-most character. It can be a non-whitespace characters that *appears* like whitespace.

Comment: This outputs 32, what does that mean?

Comment: 32 is the code of the normal space character, which should be removed by TRIM() MySQL function. Try `ORD(TRIM(text_field))`.

Comment: This helped me, my non-breaking spaces were returning code 49824.
Here is what I used to track entries and do a manual cleanup `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (ord(substr(text_field,-1))) > 255 or (ord(substr(text_field,1,1))) > 255'`

Comment: @Benjamin, 49824 decimal = C2A0 hexadecimal.  This is the 2-character UTF-8 code for NO-BREAK SPACE, Unicode (U+00A0).  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

you have to detect these "whitespace" characters first. if it's some HTML entity, like `&nbsp;` no trimming function would help, of course.

I'd suggest to print it out like this

```
echo urlenclde($row['field']);
```

and see what it says

Well as its `A0` (or 160 decimal) non-breaking space character, you can convert it to ordinal space first:

```
<pre><?php
$str = urldecode("%A0")."bla";
var_dump(trim($str));
$str = str_replace(chr(160)," ",$str);
$str = trim($str);
var_dump($str);
```

and, ta-dam! -

```
string(4) " bla"
string(3) "bla"
```

Comment: It results with: `%A0` Not sure what that translates to though.

Comment: @kylex what does it say: `echo urlencode(trim($row['field']));`

Comment: It seems like the only thing I can do is `substr($row['field'], 2)`, it's just a lot of info to process that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check what character each "whitespace" is by writing the charactercode out - It might be a non-visible charactertype that isn't removed by trim.
Trim only removes a few characters such as whitespace, tab, newline, CR and NUL but there exist other non-visible characters that might cause this problem.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), $var_text_field
```