# weird white space characters - utf8 PHP

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, whitespace

I have a weird whitespaces in string, white spaces are not white spaces. I have a problem with converting them with regex and str_replace i.e.

```
echo str_replace(' ','_',$string);
```

any ideas how to fix it? utf8_encode is also not working, regex \s either, when you copy this text to Notepad++ it shows as

```
Ê
```

instead of white space.

What I am trying to achieve is to run this regex

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/i','',$string)
```

but since those 'whitespaces' are not a whitespaces they are being removed as well.

Comment: What language are you working in? All I can tell is that it's something with `str_replace` and `utf8_encode` functions...

Comment: Could it be because of Notepad++ conversion problem instead of UTF8 PHP?

Comment: nope, php is not handling it, the use of notepad is simply to see if its whitespace or some other character, when trying to convert to utf8 in notepad it displays \xCA instead

Comment: Notepad++ probably incorrectly detects the incorrect character encoding for that character.

There's no easy way in PHP to replace all unicode characters in a string that could be considered some form of whitespace (there's many). If your target string does not support whitespace (such as urls for instance) it's actually probably more likely that there's many other characters that are not acceptable. I think if you explain what you're actually trying to achieve, there may be a different solution possible

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is to run this regex `preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/i','',$string)` but since those 'whitespaces' are not a whitespaces they are being removed as well

Comment: Regular expressions need the `u` flag to handle UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I got it, from PHP site:

You might wonder why

```
trim(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;'));
```

doesn't reduce the string to an empty string, that's because the ' ' entity is not ASCII code 32 (which is stripped by trim()) but ASCII code 160 (0xa0) in the default ISO 8859-1 characterset.

Comment: No, the trick is to do `/\xA0/u`.  Only ever deal with Unicode characters, not with serializations.

Comment: Exactly.  nbsc stands for non breaking space. It is not considered whitespace.

Comment: At HeavyDots we wrote a FUNNY post about the "strange white space" and we provided both a tool to crawl a URL and detect it and a technique we used to find and replace it in PHP. Drop by and check it out! ;-) http://heavydots.com/blog/when-the-white-space-became-a-beast