# Removing non-breaking spaces?

Tags: mysql, space

I have a query for remove all special characters.
But ONE space resists to that query at the end of email string.

Example : `'test@hotmail.com '`

```
UPDATE my_table SET email= REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(email))),\'\x0B\',\'\'),\'\0\',\'\'),\'\t\',\'\'),\'\r\',\'\'),\'\n\',\'\'),\'\r\n\',\'\'),\'\n\r\',\'\'),\' \',\'\'),CHAR(160),\'\') WHERE id=X
```

Why?

I use this statement because I have a `WHERE id IN()`, so I don't want to process special characters in PHP. I want to `UPDATE` every emails directly with `SET` and `replace`, `trim()` function.

However, some whitespace is not deleted and I don't know why.

My table has approximately 12 millions of rows. I have programmed a CRON which fetch them to delete all specials characters (unfortunately because in the past we don't had check them on `INSERT`).

So I have build this query to process my 12 MM rows. It works very great except the right whitespace (sometimes it is removed sometimes not). And I want to add that on Workbench, the query works 100% all the time. It does not make sense.

Here is my query again without backslash and with my `where IN`:

```
UPDATE NEWSLETTER_SUBSCRIPTION SET email= REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(email))),'\x0B',''),'\0',''),'\t',''),'\r',''),'\n',''),'\r\n',''),'\n\r',''),' ',''),CHAR(160),'') WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $idEmailToBeProcess) . ')
```

`$idEmailToBeProcess` contains around 500 ids.

I think the right whitespace it's a non-breaking space, but my last test with `CHAR(160)` in my query didn't work.

Comment: Why not just use a function that's specifically built for this task in whatever language you're creating the query in? IE. in PHP there is [trim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: What's your parent language? PHP? Not sure why you'd go through the effort to make that ugly nested SQL statement when you could use something like `preg_replace` in php to do it in one go.

Comment: @tenub There are three trims in the middle of the replace nest though.

Comment: I just edit my post to added some information and some detail about my workflow. Thanks guys for helping me. ^^

Comment: @coolfarmer Is it maybe an [unicode nbsp](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm)? Check if this returns 1 or 0: `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id = test_id AND hex(col_name) LIKE '%C2A0%'`, Retry the query with E28083, E28082, E280AF, EFBBBF. These are different kinds of unicode nbsp, en space, em space,... If one is positive, you got it.

Comment: You must remove char 194 before you can remove char 160.
`REPLACE(REPLACE(value, CHAR(194), ''), CHAR(160), '')`
Only Zalgo knows why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally I had found the problem !!!

Encoding of PDO is the problem...

Just adjusted driver options and all works good!

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'')
```

Thanks guys anyway!

Comment: Just change the encoding. What could possibleye go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

how about whitelisting? ie allow only valid characters

regex_replace `[^-_.@a-zA-Z]` with `''`

Comment: regexp_replace is available on MySQL ?

Comment: yes but as a [user defined function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408/mysql-regex-replace)

Answer (score 1):

Found that on MySQL checking against CHAR(160) does not work.For UTF-8 NBSP the below worked for me:

```
REPLACE(the_field, UNHEX('C2A0'), ' ').
```

Solution provided on similar stack overflow question [Whitespace in a database field is not removed by trim()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44262935)